# Unable to run a .bat file from java code using Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, hudson

I have java class that contains the following code:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start utils\"+scriptNameWithoutSpace+"\runScript.bat");

and it is working smoothly if I run it from eclipse, or from ANT or from Hudson,
but if I try to run the class from Jenkins ,the above given line of code is not working at all, and there is no error also.I'm using JDK 1.7, Jenkins 2.19.1 and ANT 1.7. Please let me know about any solution for this.

Thanks 
-Pritam

Comment: I think you may find an answer [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/My+software+builds+on+my+computer+but+not+on+Jenkins), most likely in "Desktop access (Windows)" section

Comment: I stopped the jenkins slave service and ran it from cmd prompt, now it is working as expected.